# Microsoft Graph: Organization User Details (Address Book) with Directory.AccessAsUser.All

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am building an email client, attempting to perform a search against the Graph API users endpoint, similar to what was possible in Exchange Web Services via SOAP.

In EWS with ResolveNames, the server would return details (i.e. job title, office, phone, etc.) from only the authenticated user's organization scope similar to an address book search from an email client (i.e. OWA).

Using the Graph API (which based on what I have found is the recommended API for next generation O365 email apps) the user details return `null`:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
  "businessPhones": [],
  "displayName": "John Smith",
  "givenName": "John",
  "jobTitle": null,
  "mail": "john@contoso.com",
  "mobilePhone": null,
  "officeLocation": null,
  "preferredLanguage": null,
  "surname": "Smith",
  "userPrincipalName": "john@contoso.com",
  "id": "xxxx"
}
```

I have requested the following scopes: `User.Read, User.ReadBasic.All, Calendars.Read, Calendars.ReadWrite, Calendars.Read.Shared, Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared, Contacts.Read, Contacts.Read.Shared, People.Read`

I have attempted several calls, but just a simple request for organization users demonstrates the issue:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users

Based on the documentation, it looks like this information is only visible with `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` granted--an Admin level scope which is prohibitive\impractical for a general use application.

Is there a way to perform a simple address book search with limited user details using the Graph API without admin consent?  If not, is there another API or method I can use?  Or, does Microsoft have plans to extend the Users endpoint to include this basic information?

If the user is authenticated, it seems appropriate to allow an address book\GAL\user search.

Comment: What call are you making to retrieve the user information? Also, which scopes have you requested?

Comment: Thanks @MarcLaFleur-MSFT. I have updated the question with requested information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`User.ReadBasic.All`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference?toc=./ref/toc.json&view=graph-rest-1.0#user-permissions) scope only provides access to a (no pun intended) basic set of user properties:

> Allows the app to read a basic set of profile properties of other users in your organization on behalf of the signed-in user. This includes display name, first and last name, email address, open extensions and photo. Also allows the app to read the full profile of the signed-in user.

In order to read the complete set of user properties, you need (at a minimum) to request `User.Read.All`:

> Allows the app to read the full set of profile properties, reports, and managers of other users in your organization, on behalf of the signed-in user.

This is a lot more restrictive scope than the `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` scope you mentioned, but it *does* require Admin Consent before normal users can consent to it. There is no mechanism for getting around the Admin Consent prerequisite.

Comment: Thanks again, Marc. I still stand by my assertion that access to these limited details should be available by virtue of authentication.  The same data is available by default through OWA (that is, it's already available to all authenticated O365 users, albeit with a MS application) and Admin Consent is quite prohibitive for third-party developers.  Is there a channel where I might communicate this with the Graph team?